# I specified my custom SurfaceView on the bottom layer, but sometimes it appears on top layer. Why?

Tags: android, surfaceview

I use my custom SurfaceView to display camera preview, and there are some UI elements float on SurfaceView，such as a Button to take picture. But sometimes the SurfaceView appears on top layer for some unknown reasons, I can't see any UI elements but can still interaction with them. Why?

Comment: post your xml code

Comment: Maybe it would help to show code of your custom SurfaceView. From the top of the head I can think only about setZOrderOnTop https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/SurfaceView.html#setZOrderOnTop(boolean). But you would probably know that you are using it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to read about android:layout_weight

for example :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:weightSum="2"
  android:orientation="vertical">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/layoutParent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1.7"
    android:orientation="vertical">

   // Write xml code for camera display
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/layoutParent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.3"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <Button
       android:id="@+id/Save"
       android:text="Save"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    <Button
       android:id="@+id/Cancel"
       android:text="Cancel"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

I hope it will helps you..